# Mapping C-O and C-S-O

Tags: key-bindings

I'm trying to remap <kbd>C-o</kbd> to be 'make new line below' (without going to insert mode, as opposed to `o`) and <kbd>C-S-o</kbd> 'make new line above' (without going to insert mode). I do this a lot when reformatting code. I set a mark so that I end up at the same location:

```
nnoremap <C-o> mxo<Esc>`x
noremap <C-S-o> mxO<Esc>`x
```

But it inserts a line above in both cases. Why doesn't it work? Can I make it work?

Using Terminal vim.

Comment: Related question on SO with a workaround using `.Xresources`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2179779/4194289

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's not possible inside a terminal, both keychords are interpreted as the same control character

Taken from http://catern.com/posts/terminal_quirks.html

> To send a control character to the application running in a terminal, hold down Ctrl while pressing another character. This modifies the sent character code by clearing its 7th and 6th bits (indexed starting at 1).

From [this page](http://sticksandstones.kstrom.com/appen.html) you can see that both `O` and `o` have the binary representation of `00001111` if you clear their 7th and 6th bit. Therefore the terminal can't distinguish between those two. That's a well known problem with vim and all terminal applications. It affects other chords with the control character as well.